# Show the orders sum per day T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, count, pivot

I have an **Orders** table containing this information

```
id | phone_number | Order_Date_Time
_________________________________________
1    +18001122334    2020-09-01 12:30:45
_________________________________________
2    +18001122335    2020-09-02 12:31:44
__________________________________________
3    +18001122334    2020-09-03 10:10:15
__________________________________________
4    +18001122334    2020-09-03 11:10:15
```

How can I have a query that will return the orders count per day for the last week or custom interval. For example, orders count from 2020-09-01 till 2020-09-03

```
_____________________________________________________

Phone_number | 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-02 | 2020-09-03
_____________________________________________________
+18001122334       1            NULL          2
___________________________________________________
+18001122335      NULL           1           NULL
```

Comment: You'll need to implement a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed list of dates, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select phone_number,
    sum(case when date(order_date_time) = '20200901' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_20200901,
    sum(case when date(order_date_time) = '20200902' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_20200902,
    sum(case when date(order_date_time) = '20200903' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_20200903
from orders
where order_date_time >= '20200901' and order_date_time < '20200904'
group by phone_number
```